# What are the Security Mechanisms implemented by PARSE

Tags: security, parse-platform

I'm new to parse, and have a question about the security of data in the parse.
It really speeds up the development and gives you an off-the-shelf database to store all the data coming from your web/mobile app.
How we can enforce security in parse.
Can anyone please explain me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are two levels of security. First, every connection to the Parse servers is made via SSL, every other way of trying to connect is automatically blocked by their servers. That's something you don't need to worry about, but it's good to know the connection is encrypted.

There is, however, something you can and should do, to ensure the integrity and security of your data. It's called ACL, and can be defined for every object. [Here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseACL.html) is the documentation of it. With ACL's you can define which user has read access on an object, and which user can write/edit/delete it. Additionally, you can define global ACLs via the databrowser.

Another thing worth mentioning is client enabled class creation. In development it is quite useful to have that enabled, because this means every time you call a new class which doesn't already exist, it's automatically created for you. Similarly, there is the possibility to disable the creation of new fields for a class. Also useful in development, these things should be disabled in production, unless you really have to have them enabled (which shouldn't be the case if your data structure is good enough).

Additionally, you should read [this](https://parse.com/about/security) page by Parse, it's all about security and data integrity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a great information. But I found something here http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/    How about this ?

Comment: That's another good blog post by Parse! I forgot to tell you about the keys: basically what you need to know is that the only key that should NOT, under no circumstances, be included in your code, is the master key, because it gives you full control of your application on parse. The other keys are not part of a security mechanism.

Comment: You should, however, accept the answer in case it satisfies your question.